# Prevent webpage view to go in mobile view when size is reduced beyond a certain limit

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage, which goes into mobile view when browser size is reduced. 
In all divs, I've set `col-lg-` , `col-md-` and `col-xs-` to the same values, for example:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
```

I don't want the divs to stack one above the other in mobile-view. Instead, I want them to remain the same size as in md devices and inline, with a scroll-bar added.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Post the full code , Tejasi

Comment: The code is too large to post. The crux is that all the three values are the same everywhere. I just want to get an idea of how should I proceed to not allow mobile view to be rendered, whatever is the window size of the browser.

Comment: Interesting issue.  Whenever I have this pop up on a site I'm working on, it's usually because I want a couple of elements to remain 50% 50%.  What I do is just override the bootstrap columns by setting the width to 50% at the phone breakpoint manually.  Have you tried anything like that? Edit: for some reason I can't reproduce the issue now.  What version of bootstrap?

Comment: Can you provide a demo?  Here's a basic fiddle to start off: http://jsfiddle.net/88dkop80/

Answer (score 0):

**Tejasi Latkar**, Hi there. Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/79ws7nug/)**.
And the screenshot below.
It seems that you just want to keep the same width for all views be it large or small screens... is this right?

In this demo I have set up some examples.
As you can see you can stop these divs from stacking when viewed on a small screen.

Please use this fiddle to show us what you mean if it is not what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.space {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;  
}
.space-1 {  
  margin-top: 5%;
  height:10px;  
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  background-color: blueviolet;  
}
.block {
  min-height:100px;
  background-color: orangered;    
}
.block2 {
  min-height:100px;
  background-color: steelblue;    
}    
   
@media(max-width:320px) {
p {
  font-size: .8em;
} 
h4 {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}     
}      
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container col-lg-12 space"></div>
    
    
<div class="container">

<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-6 block">
        <h4>50%</h4>
        <p>Only using <b>col-xs-6</b></p>
    </div>                                
    <div class="col-xs-6 block2">
        <h4>50%</h4>
        <p>Only using <b>col-xs-6</b></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 block2">
        <h4>50%</h4>
        <p>Only using <b>col-lg-6</b></p>
    </div>                                
    <div class="col-lg-6 block">
        <h4>50%</h4>
        <p>Only using <b>col-lgs-6</b></p>
    </div>
</div>
         
</div> <!--end container-->
    
<div class="container col-lg-12 space-1"></div>

<div class="container col-lg-12">

    <div class="row-fluid text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 block">
        <h4>50%</h4>
        <p>Using <b>col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6</b></p>
        <p>row-fluid</p>
    </div>                                
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 block2">
        <h4>50%</h4>
        <p>Using <b>col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6</b></p>
        <p>row-fluid</p>
    </div>
</div>
           
</div> <!--end container-->
    
<div class="container col-lg-12 space-1"></div>    
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

[image]